# nodejs - Filter file extensions with node-walk

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Does anyone know if it is possible to filter by extension with the node-walk module?
I only want to walk over files ending in *.log
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had a look into the source code and it only exposes the option "filters":

```
// Stop directories that contain filter keywords
// from continuing through the walk process
exclude = me._wfilters.some(function (filter) {
  if (me._wcurpath.match(filter)) {
    return true;
  }
});
```

So I used the emitter.on to the filtering:

```
walker.on('file', function(root, stat, next) {
  // Add this file to the list of files if it matches .log
  if (stat.name.match('.log')) {
    files.push(root + '/' + stat.name);
  }
  next();
});

walker.on('end', function() {
  console.log(files);
});
```

Performance wise is not the best approach but it does the job.